# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error with strcmp

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump, strcmp

The file is called "options".
Whenever I run this code in the console, here I have some possibilities:

`./options -c`
`./options -c -E`

I get the **message:**`"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` 
Dont really know what to do, I might need some help please.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        if(strcmp((argv[i],"-c") == 0)){
            printf("Argumento %d es %s\n", i, "Compilar");
        }
        else if(strcmp((argv[i],"-E") == 0)){
            printf("Argumento %d es %s\n", i, "Preprocesar");
        }  
        else if(strcmp((argv[i],"-i") == 0)){
            printf("Argumento %d es %s\n", i, "Incluir "  );
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several changes you need to make to your code:
1. add `string.h` header
2. re-write `strcmp` lines: right now it is - `strcmp((argv[i],"-c") == 0)`

With above changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        if(strcmp(argv[i],"-c") == 0){
            printf("Argumento %d es %s\n", i, "Compilar");
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-E") == 0){
            printf("Argumento %d es %s\n", i, "Preprocesar");
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[i],"-i") == 0){
            printf("Argumento %d es %s\n", i, "Incluir "  );
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out -E
Argumento 1 es Preprocesar
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with this code. First of all you should enable your compiler warnings (and always check them!). If you do, you would see something like this:

> warning: implicit declaration of function `strcmp`

which is a very important warning: it means that you forgot the proper `#include` and that the compiler will just guess, wrongly in this case.

If you look your favorite C documentation, you'll see that `strcmp` requires `#include <string.h>`. If you add that, you'll get a useful message, this time a hard error:

> error: too few arguments to function `strcmp`

And a couple of additional useful warnings:

> warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
>   warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

With that in mind, take a close inspection of your function call:

```
if(strcmp((argv[i],"-c") == 0))
```

There is only an argument to `strcmp()`, that is the result of this comparison `(argv[i],"-c") == 0`, where you compare a string `"-c"` (the left side of the comma operator is ignored) with `0` that is a `NULL` pointer. You probably want to write:

```
if (strcmp(argv[i], "-c") == 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know.